# reactjs fetch PUT value and pass value to state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: How to re-fetch after <code>PUT</code>]

```
class Mycomponent extends Component {
    state = {
        text: null
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/books/4")
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => this.setState({ text: data.title  // this data.value is "Learn Javascript" }));
    }

    fetchPUT(val) {
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/books/4", {
        method: "PUT",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ value: val })
        }).then(e => console.log(e));
    }

     onMouseDown = e => {
        this.setState({
          text: this.refs.myinput.value,
        });
        this.fetchPUT(this.refs.myinput.value);
    };
    render() {
        const { text } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  value={text}
                  onMouseLeave={this.onMouseLeave}
                  ref="myinput"
                />
            </div>
        )
     }
}
```

I'd like to sync `this.text` whenever I click button to `PUT` the value. so the flow is to `fetch` first then change value, click button `PUT` value, after `PUT`, then fetch again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to fetch the data from backend to synchronise the value with the current text. Instead use `setState` callback in your `onMouseDown` as:

```
onMouseDown = e => {
        this.setState({
          text: this.refs.myinput.value,
        }, () => {
           this.fetchPUT(this.refs.myinput.value);
        });
    };
```

Here the state will be set before it makes a put call and as you're having the updated value, you don't have to fetch the value. When the component is unmounted and mounts again, it will fetch the updated value from your `componentDidMount`.

Read more [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

**Also**

In the render function, use `onChange` instead of `onMouseDown` (Which you're not even using) because that would be less confusing. Use [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#debounce) so that you don't have to make many API calls on every change.

```
onChange = _.debounce((event) => {
   const text = event.target.value;
   this.setState({text}, () => {
       this.fetchPUT(text);
   })
}, 500)

render() {
        const { text } = this.state;
        return (
            <div>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  value={text}
                  onChange={this.onChange}
                />
            </div>
        )
     }
```

Comment: Thank you! But if I want to sync, what lifecycle method should I use?

Comment: You can use componentWillReceiveProps or componentDidUpdate. As React might deprecate componentWill* methods, you should use componentDidUpdate. You can read the documentation of React which is wonderful

Comment: I am having erros on callback to use   `this.fetchPUT(this.refs.myinput.value);` either to make a `var/const` or use `text` straight away can solve the issue. 
`onMouseDown = e => {
    const _value = this.refs.myinput.value;
    this.setState(
      {
        text: _value,
        isEditable: false
      },
      () => {

        this.fetchPUT(_value);
      }
    );
  };`